# Dynamically setting MaxLength property of a DataColumn with DataAdapter

Tags: datatable, .net-1.1

I have a datatable that I'm filling with SqlDataAdapter.Fill(). Is there a way to dynamically assign the `MaxLength` property to each string datacolumn to the maximum allowed by that column in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I googled for a while and found that the [DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.aspx) has another method besides `Fill` which is: [FillSchema()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/152bda9x.aspx), which includes the database schema into the `DataTable`. Since all I wanted to bring was the [MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.maxlength.aspx) property what I did was load the schema into another table and loop through the columns assigning the value to each one.

Of course if you wanted to keep all the constraints in the database within your table, then you'd need no loop and just load the schema into the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

PedroC88's answer worked. To clarify the code needed for any newbies. Just above my adapters fill method, I wrote the fillschema method. The (SchemaType)2 argument is required. There are 2 different [schematypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.schematype?view=net-5.0) (1 and 2) and 2 is recommended as it applies existing table mappings (though I have no idea what this means).

```
myAdapter.FillSchema(dataTable, (SchemaType)2);
myAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
```

In this code 'myAdapter' is the name of my adapter and 'dataTable' is the name of my data table.