# Varchar(N) being ignored in DataTable.Load()

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable

Possible that I'm overlooking something here, but when I load a DataTable from `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` I am finding that the MaxLength property of my String field is ignored and reset to '50' in the resulting DataColumn. Here's an example table:

```
CREATE TABLE MySqlServerTable (
[instance_id] INT           NOT NULL,
[field_id]    INT           NOT NULL,
[value]       VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL);
```

and the method I'm using to initialize the local DataTable is

```
public DataTable GetDT()
{
    string query = "SELECT top 0 * FROM MySqlServerTable;";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, _msSqlConn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    return dt;
}
```

where _msSqlConn is the already opened SqlConnection. If I then scroll through the DataColumns, I find that the value column (the string column) has been assigned a MaxLength of 50.

```
Console.WriteLine(GetDT().Columns["value"].MaxLength);
```

So what gives?

Kinda related to [this attempted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6954200/969367) but still unresolved.

What's the right way to do this such that my string column MaxLengths are properly retrieved from the SqlServer2012 DB?

Comment: Just wondering why you select `Top 0`?, Do you have any data in the actual table?

Comment: Perhaps all you really need is the schema? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6873380/211627

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use `DataAdapter.FillSchema()` to retrieve meta data. Try this something like this:

```
_msSqlConn.Open();
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, _msSqlConn))
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Mapped); //Or may be SchemaType.Source
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Yes. That was it. Filling the schema. Thanks Kaf and Cybȫʁgϟ37